# POST data from Python script to Flask

Tags: python, http, flask, python-requests

I am trying to send data from a python script to flask endpoint.
I have tried many things but I don't understand where I am going wrong.
Please let me know if you have a solution or any reference that can help me.

Thanks in advance

This is the Flask code which gets json data:

```
@app.route('/ramp-DynDB-DQ-PostTableItem', methods=['POST' , 'GET'])
def PostDQTableItem():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
```

This is the Python Script that Posts data:

```
 import requests

newHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.post('http://blabla:5000/ramp-DynDB-DQ-PostTableItem',
                        data={"Key": "key", "Path": "path"},
                        headers=newHeaders)
```

Status code:

```
400
```

Comment: Your client code does not post any JSON.

Comment: correct me if  I am wrong , I am guessing this is the JSON data={"Key": "key", "Path": "path"}

Comment: No, it's not. It's a regular Python dict. And `requests` will take that dict and transform it into the standard format for HTTP POSTs, which looks like this: `Key=key&Path=path`. You have two options: **a)** Change your client code so that it sends JSON. **b)** Change your server code so that it also accepts standard POST requests.

Comment: Can You give me example brother, I am okay to change both client or server code

Comment: There are many examples, have a look around. The standard format for HTTP POST requests is called `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the JSON format is called `application/json`. With these keywords you should find plenty of examples for both `flask` and `requests`.

Comment: Thanks Man, Problem solved :), you are right in saying it's just dictionary, dumped it as json format and code worked

Comment: Very good, that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Converting Dict to JSON format worked for me:

```
import requests, json

data = {"Key": "key", 
        "Path": "path"
        }

json_object = json.dumps(data, indent = 4)   
print(json_object) 
newHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
res = requests.get('http://blabla/ramp-DynDB-DQ-PostTableItem')
response = requests.post('http://blabla/ramp-DynDB-DQ-PostTableItem',
                        data=json_object,
                        headers=newHeaders)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: You don't need to do all that `requests` has a `json` attribute:  `requests.post('http://blahblah/etc', json=data)` would do the same as the above code.
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: I tried that Doobeh, for some reason it said json is not recognized